# Is "bicycle born human" correct in this context?

Tags: sentence-construction

**Context:** Person X likes to ride his bicycle. The context is a morning in a normal road, with a commonplace setting in a simple town locality. Some are riding bicycles, while others are riding scooters. I want to write:

> While he doesn’t let go of scooters without a race, he makes it a point to not let any ***bicycle born human*** overtake him, and if they do so, he would overtake them back again within a minute.

By "While he doesn’t let go of scooters without a race", I mean to say that he does try to challenge scooters for a race, and evidently looses since he himself is on a bicycle. However, he does not let any other bicyclist overtake him. And if by chance any bicyclist overtakes him, he'll make it a point to overtake them back.

**Question:**

Is "bicycle born human" a correct usage? I am avoiding the term "biker" or "bicyclist" because this is a simple setting, so there are people like the milkman, the breadman, the newspaperman, etc. who are just riding a simple bicycle to commute from one place to another. I am worried that those two words refer to a rather exclusive set of adventurous cyclists with helmets on their heads.

PS: I hope it's obvious but, through that phrase, I want to refer to a human riding a bicycle, not a human "born" on a bicycle :P

Comment: Can you explain how you came up with that expression in the first place? What was your reasoning?

Comment: @CookieMonster I felt like I've heard phrases before which in general mean "y-born => being carried by y"...

Comment: I think I got you now. The guy in question must be some kind of tailgater.

Comment: @CookieMonster Thanks but No, that's not what I'd in mind. I did not mention tailgating. I meant person X to clearly *overtake* other bicycle born people.

Comment: Why don't you just use simpler language? Forget all that fancy vocabulary. Just say what you want to say in simple words.

Comment: @CookieMonster I agree with you. I was initially under the impression that "bicycle born human" is not an awkward construct, but I have been proved wrong. I'll accept your answer once you update it a bit. Thank you!

Comment: You're misusing "let go of" and "overtake them... *back* again".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Please also explain why you think so. It isn't immediately obvious for me. Thank you!

Comment: I will add to the answer rather than extend the comments.

Comment: Are you possibly looking for "borne" (carried by) not "born" (having been birthed by)? In that case, you would say "bicycle-borne human" and it's a slightly strange, but understandable, way of speaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He doesn't let anyone on a bicycle overtake him.

With respect to "let go of".  The desired meaning is not clear to me in OP's **while** construction:

*While he doesn’t let go of scooters without a race, he makes it a point to not let any bicycle born human overtake him, and if they do so, he would overtake them back again within a minute.*

The expected structure is "While (although) he does not do X, he does do Y". Since he *does* wish to prevent anyone on a bicycle from overtaking him, the contrary of that would be "he ignores people on scooters". But "doesn’t let go of [sic] scooters without a race" does not have that meaning. I think OP means to use this construction: "let {someone} go without {something}":

> He lets people on scooters go without a race...

That is, he does not bother to race people on scooters.

With respect to "back again", "back" is incorrect.

**back** = restored to an original place

Here is what you want to say:

> .. He would overtake them again in a minute.

A runner, say, or race-car driver,  who is in the lead, if he is overtaken, can *get the lead position back* or *get the lead position back again*.

> I will lend you this book. I would like it **back again.**

Comment: (+1) That's actually quite neat!

Comment: **anyone** is a very useful word :)  But it is easy to see how the phrase **anyone on a bicycle** might confuse or elude a learner!

Comment: Thanks for elaborating! In this part -> "He lets people on scooters go without a race..." I actually meant to say something like "He definitely tries to race with scooters, but doesn't push too much if they take the lead. However, losing to one scooter does not deter his zeal, so he'll try to race with the next scooter as well." Can this information be decently presented in a sentence?

Comment: OK, the contrast wasn't clear to me between his actions vs scooters and his actions vs bicyclists.  Is the following a decent paraphrase of your intended meaning?  *He is willing to concede victory to scooters, though even they do not get by without a race;  but he is unwilling to lose to a bicycle and  quickly gets the lead back again when anyone on a bicycle overtakes him.*

Comment: Thanks! I now feel that the whole scooter thing is making the sentence very clumsy. I think I should delete that bit about scooters. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Honestly speaking, I don't think that's a correct usage of the adjective [**borne**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/borne) (and please pay attention to the spelling). An airborne disease is one that's transfered from person to person through the air. Waterborne diseases are diseases that are spread through water. The idea here is that the first word (for example, *air* in *airborne*) in an expression so formed tells you what medium is used to carry the disease. I think, the most common usage of **borne** (there are some other less common ones) you typically hear is when people are talking about diseases and bacteria that cause them. I don't know why, but **borne** just doesn't seem to work for humans. You could say, however, *airborne troops*, but that's rather a technicality. It seems to me that this word is only applicable to things that are not human and have no intellectual capacity to make decisions on their own. That's probably why we can say *airborne troops*. The reason, I think, is because soldiers can't give orders, they must follow them instead. So, I would suggest that you look for an alternative way to describe a person who likes to ride bikes.

In your situation, you could simply say **any bicyclist**. Though not as fancy-sounding, at least a lot more comprehensible. **bicycle borne human** would literally mean a person who is carried by means of bicycles, but that's just not idiomatic and sounds like awfully awkward English. It gives the impression that they have no choice in whether they want to be transfered by bicycles or not just like waterborne bacteria have no ability to decide where to go. They go where the media takes them.

Could you please tell us some more about your sentence and what idea exactly you want to express with it because as it stands right now, the sentence is not the most intelligible one. The only thing that I can discern is that you're talking about a person who can give others a run for their money when it comes to bicycle racing. And if you do tell us more about your sentence, hopefully we will be able to fix it together. It's very difficult to come up with the right descriptives when the exact context is unclear or vague.

Comment: References like https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/borne include usages like *the railroad-borne news* and definitions like *transported or transmitted by*. Also, I don't believe I was technically a disease when I was an airborne soldier.

Comment: Thanks. I believe your definition is too narrow, but we'll see what the community thinks.

Comment: Yep, "borne" was the first thing I thought of when seeing the OP's question. And I believe the passage in question refers to someone who is competitive on/in a (motor) vehicle; specifically "while he doesn’t let go of scooters without a race" refers to the person referred to always racing people on (motor?) scooters; and doing the same with bicyclists with mixed results.

Comment: "while he doesn’t let go of scooters without a race." I meant to say that he always challenges the scooterists for a race

Comment: **let go of** is just not the expression you would want to use because it means something that's entirely different from you're trying to say. Capisce?

Comment: @CookieMonster I have expanded the question. Please have a look. I used "let go of" because the dictionary said, "allow someone or something to escape or go free". Though I am unaware if this was a contextual blunder.

Answer (score 1):

No, 'bicycle born human' is not the correct term for refering to somebody riding a bicycle, because this person is not born on or from a bicycle. They are simply called a **[cyclist](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cyclist)** or **[biker](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/biker?s=t)**.

If you really want to avoid using those terms, you could always use **person riding a bicycle**.

While **bicycle borne human** is not incorrect, it does look rather awkward in everyday usage and could be downright confusing.

Comment: To extend this answer a bit, 'borne' is the past tense of 'bear' in the sense of 'carry' eg 'the burden that I bear' vs ' the burden that I have borne '.

Comment: If I felt absolutely compelled to use it, I think I might be inclined to hyphenate the term: _bicycle-borne human_. But 99% of the time I think I'd heed your advice and avoid the term altogether.

Comment: I have expanded the context of the question if you wish to have a look. Thank you!

Comment: While I edited my answer slighty, I still advice you should just use either (bi)cyclist or biker, as these words do not just apply to sportsmen, but to all people riding a bicycle.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not, "**bicycle born human**" is ridiculous. You can, however, use the phrasing "**born to ride a bicycle**" or call them a "***(bi)* cyclist**". You could also call such a person a "**biker**" but it could either mean "*a person riding a bicycle*" or "*a person riding a motorcycle*".

Comment: I have expanded the context of the question if you wish to have a look. Thank you!

Comment: I actually see the paragraph like this: "**Even though he loses challenges in racing to scooters, he makes it a point not to allow other bicycle riders overtake him. If still they do, he makes an effort to overtake them back within a minute.**"

Comment: Well, he doesn't actually "challenge" the scooters per se. So, I think a better adaptation of your sentence would be: "Even though he loses to scooters, he makes it a point to not allow other bicycle riders overtake him. If they still manage to do so, he makes an effort to overtake them back within a minute." What do you think?

Comment: @GaurangTandon he doesn't try to race them? He losses before he starts?

Comment: It's OK though if you use "borne", for example [Gifts For the Bicycle Borne Road Warrior](https://gizmodo.com/gifts-for-the-bicycle-riding-road-warrior-1477386708) or [A long-range, bicycle-borne banana-vendor](http://www.vietnamheritage.com.vn/pages/en/199113242171-A-long-range-bicycle-borne-banana-vendor.html)